# Как отправить массив в телеграмм?

Tags: python, массивы, telegram, бот

Всем привет! Пишу программу(логгер), в телеграмм бота надо вывести массив

```
PressedButtonsArray = []
```

В нём содержится около 20 значений, потом они обнуляются. При выводе массива в бота с помощью

```
import telebot;
bot = telebot.TeleBot('token')

@bot.message_handler(content_types=['text'])


def echo_all(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, PressedButtonsArray)
    bot.infinity_polling()
```

выводится лишь первое значение. Значение это выводится с ответом на любое моё сообщение, как и должно быть. Как вывести все значения массива?

Comment: сделать из массива строку и её отправить?

Comment: Сам массив не как. A вот элементы массива, пожалуй можно (например через цикл)